# what does "negative fashion" mean?

Tags: meaning

"In negative fashion, if I can establish that both positions fail for various reasons this would be sufficient to establish the two main theses of hard(-enough) determinism."

Free Will and Consciousness: A Determinist Account of the Illusion of Free Will
by Gregg D. Caruso

what does "negative fashion" mean?

Comment: Negative: proving something fails. Positive: proving something works.

Comment: all right. thank you. but if I wanna take this term and put a synonym for this term instead, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with *reasoning* in a negative fashion. This isn't everyday vocabulary. It means an approach to logic where you improve knowledge by showing what *isn't* true.

"Fashion" here has its sense of "manner"; you could rephrase it as "in negative manner" and maintain the same meaning.